# Difference between list and matrixcursor (Android)

Tags: android, list, matrixcursor

I'm trying to make a new android project in which I collect my data from an online JSON file.
If I look on the internet, I can see a lot of examples where they are storing the collected data in a MatrixCursor. 
Personally, I think it's much easier (and much shorter/faster) to store all the data in a list in a model class. 
Is there a good reason why they are not using Lists instead of MatrixCursor, or what are the differences between them ?

Comment: yes, you can use it with out-of-the-box SimpleCursorAdapter, for example see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830 on how to show some web service api in ACTV

Comment: You can store data from an online JSON file in an ArrayAdapter as well, or  am I wrong ?

Comment: sure, but how would you make ACTV to work with ArrayAdapter? hehehe see this question asked 5 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367712/autocompletetextview-adapter-not-set

Comment: Who said that I want to use ACTV ? :p
And you can also filter on a list if you want (it's maybe al little bit more work)

Comment: you didn't say what component you want to use, besides in most cases you need a custom ArrayAdapter if your data item is not one TextView, with SCA and MC in most cases you don't need any custom adapters

Comment: Post some links for the examples using MatrixCursor, and we can look at each of them and see if MatrixCursor provides any real advantage over a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer to have model classes that can be created from JSON data along with a custom `ListAdapter` for those classes.

However, there are components such as `SearchView` that specifically require a `CursorAdapter` i.e. for search suggestions.  In those cases. it's easier to put the data into a cursor like a `MatrixCursor`, pass that to a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and be done with it.

Comment: Last week, I made a project using the `SearchView` with a normal list. So the `SearchView` doesn't explicitly require a `CursorAdapter`

Comment: @NickSpriet, sure you can do it but you need a 1) setOnCloseListener 2) custom POJO do store data 3) custom background search Thread/AsyncTask 4) custom adapter, and with CursorAdapter you can do it directly as i did in the link i posted above, now what is much easier (and much shorter/faster)?

Comment: @pskink nope, I didn't need all that stuff. The `SearchView` has an `setOnQueryTextListener`. You can use `onQueryTextChange` to filter and update your list.

Comment: @NickSpriet of course i meant `setOnQueryTextListener` (bad copy/paste) , so you need: 1) setOnQueryTextListener , the rest is the same...