# AutoCompleteTextView adapter not set

Tags: android, android-activity, autocompletetextview

I have a class that fetches all the suggestions based on the text entered from the server. In the postExecute(), I am adding all the suggestions to my ArrayList and I want to set that arraylist as adapter. But it is not working.

The onCreate() code:

```
     t1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) 
            findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);



    t1.setThreshold(1);
    t1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           //DoPost() is the class fetching data from server
            new DoPOST().execute("");

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,Names);
    t1.setAdapter(adp);
```

When I change the text, I can see the server response returning the data. And in postExecute():

```
for(int i=0 ;i<js.length();i++){
            try {
                JSONObject tokenobj=js.getJSONObject(i);
                Names.add(tokenobj.get("suggestion").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
```

So the suggestions are coming in the arraylist but it is not showing as the dropdown instantly..
Please help,
Thanx in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/30366972/2252830

Answer (score 1):

When the data (the ArrayList in this case) changes, you need to call `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter instance in order for the view to redraw.